# Protecting files on android

Tags: android, security

My group and I have an application that will work with protected content files that could (or not) contain pretty sensitive information. So we have to ensure they will not be copied by the user.

This question is specifically about the micro USB port. Is there a way to programmatically block it so that the user will be unable to mount trough it to copy our files?

Any and all help/counsel/answers are appreciated. :)

*Additional Information:The application will be pat of a custom home application, so we will have that to out advantage, if that is any help.*

Comment: Apart from the (possible) proper answer to your question, another layer of security: encryption. I am in the initial stages of designing such a system and each device will have its owns public-private key and the data will be encoded using these. Of course if the device is compromised then the keys there are in risk too, but it is an extra layer to weed out the less sophisticated attempts.

Comment: Thanks, and yes we will be using pretty strong encryption, but we still need to make sure the files won't be copied, our client does not trust encryption alone.

Comment: Why not just put it in the local folder in the user data area? Then only your app can access it. This ofcourse does not protect vs rooted device users

Comment: What is your target API level?

Comment: API level 12
Files are to big for internal storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 100% safe solution for file storage. If you store the files on the SDCard they will have zero protection. If you store them on the internal filesystem you will be protected by file system permissions, which will generally prevent other apps getting to your files. But if the user roots their phone, nothing will stop them getting the files off the phone. Most phones can be rooted.

If you want to protect the sensitive information from your users, look for a way to store it on the network instead. If you only want to protect against other apps, for users that haven't rooted, the internal filesystem should be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The application would work on a controlled enviroment on select phones that will be our property. The user wouldn't be able to remove the SDCard in any way.
Our files however are too big for internal storage, probably several gigs

Answer (score 1):

The above are correct and to add, suppose you do disable the USB?  Then I'll just Bluetooth them off.  Ah, you disabled Bluetooth.  OK, I'll use ADB shell over WiFi.  Damn, you thought of that too.  OK, I'll copy them with Root Explorer to my Dropbox folder.  Wait, you got me, I'll email them instead...

You get the picture ;)

I am of the opinion that there is no totally secure file in Android.  It's just a question of how difficult you can make it to lock out the 99% of "average" crackers.